# WPF XAML Binding Reference String

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, resources

Note: I'm just using the standard Books inventory example used by Microsoft.  Ultimately what I am trying to do is change the xPath element of the XmlDataProvider to 'Inventory/Books' or 'Inventory/CDs' depending on the user's selection in the combo-box.

So when a user clices on the combo-box and selects CDs, it will change the xPath text from 'Inventory/Books' to 'Inventory/CDs' or vice versa.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>

        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Inventory" Source="Invenstory.xml" XPath="Inventory/CDs" />

    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ComboBox Name="MyComboBox" Width="200" Height="40" Margin="25" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="Books" Tag="Books" IsSelected="True" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="CDs" Tag="CDs" />
            </ComboBox>

            <TextBox Name="MyTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue.Content, ElementName=MyComboBox, StringFormat=Invenstory/{0}}" Width="200" Height="40" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />


        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm relatively new to this, but I've tried multiple ways of doing it, by including it in a Resource Dictionary etc.  All chances haven't worked for me.  Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve here. The ComboBox switches "Books" or "CDs". Then what consumes "Inventory"?

Comment: Sorry, was having a tough time to explain, there are more controls that will utilize the inventory, so what I'm looking for is a way to change the xPath depending on what is chosen in the combo-box.  So if they choose Books, it changes to Inventory/Books, if they choose CDs, it changes the xPath to Inventory/CDs.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You can specify XPath at binding instead of XmlDataProvider itself. We don't know your actual bindings but perhaps you can replace one with another with different XPath depending on the ComboBox's SelectedValue.